# Move/drag/zoom an imageview in Android

Tags: android, imageview

I am developing an app which takes a picture from camera and then applies an imageview on top of it.
Now, I need to move and resize (with pinch) the imageview above the captured picture.

First I've implemented a simple drag behavior which worked well (I cannot use the drag event since min sdk level), but problems have came when I tried to add a pinch-to-zoom action too.

Right now I've tried several solutions found on stackoverflow, but none of them has worked for my scenario.

Here is the custom view that I'm using (found after some searchs)
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/230145/PanZoomView.java

but it has a weird behavior since when I try to do a zoom or drag it, the object gets crazy  on the screen.

Anyone has an idea or solution for this?

**EDIT**

Finally I've solved with the following code:

Code from Java Class:

```
private ImageView mOrologio;
private FrameLayout mPhotoBox;
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// Remember some things for zooming
PointF start = new PointF();
PointF mid = new PointF();
float oldDist = 1f;

...
...

private void bindViews(View rootView) {
    ...
    mPhotoBox = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fotoBox);

    mOrologio = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgOrologio);
    mOrologio.setOnTouchListener(this);
    ...
}

private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            mode = DRAG;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            if (oldDist > 10f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mode == DRAG) {
                // ...
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                        event.getY() - start.y);
            }
            else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                float newDist = spacing(event);
                if (newDist > 10f) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                }
            }
            break;
    }

    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    return true; // indicate event was handled
  }
}
```

Code from XML Layout:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fotoBox"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/prev_list" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imgOrologio"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

So basically I've learned this lesson:

- FrameLayout is needed as rootView if you want to move/zoom your ImageView
- If you want to move/zoom an ImageView like in my scenario you don't need to override the ImageView class but only handle the touch events.

Thank you all for replies and hope this solution will be usefull =)

Comment: my observation is for your solution FrameLayout isn't necessary at all, this can work with out it.. the only thing required is to set scaleType to "matrix".

Answer (score 8):

You can use a custom image view above the current screen using a frame layout. You can use the custom class here will may help you

```
 public class CustomZoomableImageView  extends ImageView {
private Paint borderPaint = null;
private Paint backgroundPaint = null;

private float mPosX = 0f;
private float mPosY = 0f;

private float mLastTouchX;
private float mLastTouchY;
private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
private static final String LOG_TAG = "TouchImageView";

// The ‘active pointer’ is the one currently moving our object.
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

public CustomZoomableImageView (Context context) {
    this(context, null, 0);
}

public CustomZoomableImageView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

// Existing code ...
public CustomZoomableImageView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // Create our ScaleGestureDetector
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());

    borderPaint = new Paint();
    borderPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 128, 0);
    borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(4);

    backgroundPaint = new Paint();
    backgroundPaint.setARGB(32, 255, 255, 255);
    backgroundPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

    final int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();

        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;

        mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
        final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
        final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

        // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
        if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
            final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
            final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

            mPosX += dx;
            mPosY += dy;

            invalidate();
        }

        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
        final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
        final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
        if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
            // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
            // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
            final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
            mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
            mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
        }
        break;
    }
    }

    return true;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.view.View#draw(android.graphics.Canvas)
 */
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, borderPaint);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, backgroundPaint);
    if (this.getDrawable() != null) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, pivotPointX,
                pivotPointY);
        // canvas.setMatrix(matrix);

        canvas.drawBitmap(
                ((BitmapDrawable) this.getDrawable()).getBitmap(), matrix,
                null);

        // this.getDrawable().draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see
 * android.widget.ImageView#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
 * )
 */
@Override
public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    // Constrain to given size but keep aspect ratio
    int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    mLastTouchX = mPosX = 0;
    mLastTouchY = mPosY = 0;

    int borderWidth = (int) borderPaint.getStrokeWidth();
    mScaleFactor = Math.min(((float) getLayoutParams().width - borderWidth)
            / width, ((float) getLayoutParams().height - borderWidth)
            / height);
    pivotPointX = (((float) getLayoutParams().width - borderWidth) - (int) (width * mScaleFactor)) / 2;
    pivotPointY = (((float) getLayoutParams().height - borderWidth) - (int) (height * mScaleFactor)) / 2;
    super.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}

float pivotPointX = 0f;
float pivotPointY = 0f;

private class ScaleListener extends
        ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        pivotPointX = detector.getFocusX();
        pivotPointY = detector.getFocusY();

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "mScaleFactor " + mScaleFactor);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "pivotPointY " + pivotPointY + ", pivotPointX= "
                + pivotPointX);
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.05f, mScaleFactor);

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

And call the setImageDrawableMethod in the custom imageView

Comment: thank you for this code. I'll try it asap. only one doubt, should I use a relativelayout instead of a framelayout??

Comment: @SaverioAxlGuardato you don't need a FrameLayout nor RelativeLayout. Just make a match_parent match_parent ImageView a root view.

Comment: @Vyshnavi Thanks.....+1 vote for u....but tell me how can i stop imageview dragging out of the some views or mobile device.

Comment: and Is it possible to drawimage drawable direct instead of  touch....?? plz tell me if you know.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to crop the image. I can not comment on your post but just answer. If so then let me know because you can use CROP intent to for what you are looking for. I have implemented it and it basically takes picture with camera... crops,zooms and drag .

Comment: no, I'm not editing or cropping the image taken with camera, it's just set as background of my relativelayout. 
I need to do drag/zoom actions on an imageview which is shown above that relativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
  Something like below will do it.

```
@Override public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent e)
{

    tap=tap2=drag=pinch=none;
    int mask=e.getActionMasked();
    posx=e.getX();posy=e.getY();

    float midx= img.getWidth()/2f;
    float midy=img.getHeight()/2f;
    int fingers=e.getPointerCount();

    switch(mask)
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            tap2=1;break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            tap=1;break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drag=1;
    }
    if(fingers==2){nowsp=Math.abs(e.getX(0)-e.getX(1));}
    if((fingers==2)&&(drag==0)){ tap2=1;tap=0;drag=0;}
    if((fingers==2)&&(drag==1)){ tap2=0;tap=0;drag=0;pinch=1;}

    if(pinch==1)

    {
        if(nowsp>oldsp)scale+=0.1;
        if(nowsp<oldsp)scale-=0.1;
        tap2=tap=drag=0;    
    }
    if(tap2==1)
        {
            scale-=0.1;
            tap=0;drag=0;
        }
    if(tap==1)
        {
            tap2=0;drag=0;
            scale+=0.1;
        }
    if(drag==1)
        {
            movx=posx-oldx;
            movy=posy-oldy;
            x+=movx;
            y+=movy;
            tap=0;tap2=0;
        }
    m.setTranslate(x,y);
    m.postScale(scale,scale,midx,midy);
    img.setImageMatrix(m);img.invalidate();
    tap=tap2=drag=none;
    oldx=posx;oldy=posy;
    oldsp=nowsp;
    return true;
}


public void onCreate(Bundle b)
{
        super.onCreate(b);

    img=new ImageView(this);
    img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    img.setOnTouchListener(this);

    path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();   
    path=path+"/DCIM"+"/behala.jpg";
    byte[] bytes;
    bytes=null;
    try{
        FileInputStream fis;
        fis=new FileInputStream(path);
        BufferedInputStream bis;
        bis=new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        bytes=new byte[bis.available()];
        bis.read(bytes);
        if(bis!=null)bis.close();
        if(fis!=null)fis.close();

     }
    catch(Exception e)
        {
        ret="Nothing";
        }
    Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length);

    img.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    setContentView(img);
}
```

For viewing complete program see here: [Program to zoom image in android](https://letsmakeandroidapp.wordpress.com/doing-image-zoom-drag-pan-in-android-java/)